# Post request with multiple parameters using Twisted Web Client

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I would like to send a POST request with multiple parameters using Twisted Web Client :

- image : image
- metadata : json document with meta data
  I need to use pure Twisted without external libraries like Treq and requests.

At the moment, I can send only one parameter and tried few ways without success.

Do someone know how to change body to achieve this goal ?

```
from __future__ import print_function

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

from bytesprod import BytesProducer

agent = Agent(reactor)
body = BytesProducer(b"hello, world")
d = agent.request(
    b'POST',
    b'http://httpbin.org/post',
    Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example'],
             'Content-Type': ['text/x-greeting']}),
    body)

def cbResponse(ignored):
    print('Response received')
d.addCallback(cbResponse)

def cbShutdown(ignored):
    reactor.stop()
d.addBoth(cbShutdown)

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify how you would like the parameters encoded.  If you want to to submit them like a browser form, you need to application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data encode the data.  The former is generally for short data - and since of your parameters is "image" it probably isn't short.  So you should multipart/form-data the data.

Once you have, you just declare this in the request head and include the encoded data in the body.

For example,

```
body = multipart_form_encoded_body_producer(your_form_fields))
d = agent.request(
    b'POST',
    b'http://httpbin.org/post',
    Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example'],
             'Content-Type': ['multipart/form-data']}),
    body)
```

Conveniently, [treq](https://treq.readthedocs.io/en/release-20.3.0/index.html) provides [a multipart/form-data encoder](https://treq.readthedocs.io/en/release-20.3.0/api.html#multipartproducer-objects)

So `multipart_form_encoded_body_producer(...)` probably looks something like:

```
MultiPartProducer([
    ("image", image_data),
    ("metadata", some_metadata),
    ...
])
```

You mentioned that you can't use Treq.  You didn't mention why.  I recommend using Treq or at least finding another library that can do the encoding for you.  If you can't do that for some unreasonable reason, you'll have to implement multipart/form-data encoding yourself.  It is [reasonably well documented](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) and of course there are multiple implementations you can also use as references and interoperability testing tools.

Comment: It's in embedded with a lot of resources constrain. Treq haves a long list of dependencies and is quite slow to import in our tests. I would like to use pure twisted solution to avoid those issues. Otherwise, I would be glad to use Treq....

Comment: I will try to use the source code of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twisted/treq/master/src/treq/multipart.py to have the best of both world.